# Avoid mass e-mail notification in error analysis bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, raspberry-pi

I am selecting error log details from a docker container and decide within a shell script, how and when to alert about the issue by discord and/or email.

Because I am receiving the email alerts too often with the same information in the email body, I want to implement the following two adjustments:

Fatal error log selection:

```
FATS="$(docker logs --since 24h $NODENAME 2>&1 | grep 'FATAL' | grep -v 'INFO')"
```

Email sent, in case FATS has some content:

```
swaks --from "$MAILFROM" --to "$MAILTO" --server "$MAILSERVER" --auth LOGIN --auth-user "$MAILUSER" --auth-password "$MAILPASS" --h-Subject "FATAL ERRORS FOUND" --body "$FATS" --silent "1"
```

How can I send the email only in the case, FATS has another content than the previous run of the script? I have thought about a hash about its content, which is stored and read in a text file. If the hash is the same than the previous script run, the email will be skipped.

Another option could be a local, temporary variable in the global user's bash profile, so that there is no file to be stored on the file system (to avoid read / writes).

How can I do that?

Comment: How about changing the --since to the interval you are running the script? You should only get new messages then ...

Comment: haha, indeed. will rewrite the script to do that. @RalfDraeger

Comment: Additionally: `FATS="$(echo $LOG1H 2>&1 | grep 'FATAL' | grep -v 'INFO')"` should work as well, right (echo log1h)? I should make the log selection just once and can speed up the script by doing that.

Comment: `that there is no file to be stored on the file system` Use a file. `(to avoid read / writes)` Store the file in memory. Shell work on files, use files.

Comment: Hi, based on RalfDraeger's feedback, I want to limit docker log extraction to once the script runs. Is there a limitation, how many chars a shell variable can take? And: I don not understand, why the INFO variable, which contains a log excerpt, cannot be echo'd and grep'd - the following statement does not work: `tmp_info="$(echo $INFO 2>&1 | grep 'INFO' | grep -v -e 'FATAL' -e 'ERROR' -c)"`. Result is 1 or 0, but never 5,500 - the number of correct counts of INFO log entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I‘ve chosen the proposal of @ralf-dreager and reduced selection to 1d and 1h. Consequently, I‘ve changed my monitoring script to either go through the results of 1d or just 1h, without the need to select each time again and again. Huge performance improvement and no need to store anything else in a variable or on the file system.

```sh
FATS="$(docker logs --since 1h $NODENAME 2>&1 | grep 'FATAL' | grep -v 'INFO')"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing a script for your monitoring, add functions for additional functionality, like:

- logging all the alerts that have been send
- make sure you don't send more than 1 alert each hour
- consider sending warnings only during working hours
- escalate a message when it fails N times without intermediate success
- possible send an alert to different receivers (different email adresses or also to sms or teams)
- make an interface for an operator so he can look back when something went wrong the first time.

When you have control which messages you send, it is easy to filter duplicate meassages (after changing `--since`).